# My class @Component not updated with my model

Tags: spring, primefaces, spring-webflow

I have a class markeup with "@Component" and have a modelView, the property of model use in the view not is update in action the button active.

```java
@Component
public class MyBbean extends BaseBBean<MyBbean>{
    @Autowired AnyService anyTitulos;
    private myModel model;
}
```

My flow reference:

```
<on-start>
<evaluate result="flowScope.modelView" expression="myBbean.getModel()"/>
</on-start>
<view-state id="view" >
<transition on="action">
<evaluate  expression="myBbean.anyAction()"/>
</transition>
</view-state>
```

My view:

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<p:inputText id="teste1" value="#{modelView.test}"  required="true"/>  
<p:commandButton action="action" immediate="true" />
```

When I look up the property test in model, it is null...

Comment: try removing immediate attribute. It's skips validation and updation phase as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem using scope session

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
```